# Counting posts with argument without retrieving the posts

Tags: wpdb, get-posts, count

I have a quite extensive database, 30000+ items, and using this:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'post_type'       => 'books',
    's'               => $s
);

$post_counts = count(get_posts($args));
```

seems to take forever.

```
I solved this particular case with:

$post_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'books' AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_title LIKE '%".$s."%'");
```

But I have many queries that I'd like to count without having to write them by hand. Is there any way to count the posts with the $args using wordpress native functions without having to store the whole querie but only the count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one thing you could do. Create a WP_Query object but only include ids:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'books',
    's'                 => $s,
    'fields'            => 'ids',
);

$query          = new WP_Query( $args );
$post_counts    = $query->post_count;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

By using [`fields => ids`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Return_Fields_Parameter) you're only returning the IDs. Also, WP_Query already does a count and supplies it as a property: [`post_count`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties). Finally, since we are using a WP_Query we need to reset the globals with [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata).

Answer (score 2):

When `WP_Query` generates a SQL query with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and a `LIMIT` clause:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ... FROM ...  WHERE ...  LIMIT ...
```

then the total number of rows:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

is available from the `found_posts` property of `WP_Query`.

---

This means we can fetch a single post with:

```
'posts_per_page' => 1 // not -1
```

and get the total count from

```
$total = $query->found_posts;
```

where `$query` is the `WP_Query` object.

---

From the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows):

> FOUND_ROWS():
>
> For a SELECT with a LIMIT clause, the number of rows that would be
>   returned were there no LIMIT clause

It's also informative to look at [`WP_Query::set_found_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/set_found_posts/) to see how the `found_posts` property is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

There is `$wpdb->num_rows` parameter. 
But I suggest you do it with

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) ... )
```

This should be much faster if I am not mistaken. It's related to mysql internal functions.

> When doing COUNT, the server will only allocate memory to store the result of the count.

> When using mysql_num_rows, the server will process the entire result set, allocate memory for all those results